# Linear maps from R³ to R²

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two linear maps $f_1,f_2:\ \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^2$ is there a $x\neq 0$ such that $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$?

My take: The map $f_1-f_2$ can't be injective so it must have some non-trivial kernel of which I can take any non-zero vector $x$ that satisfies $(f_1-f_2)(x)=0$ and thus the equation above. Is this correct? Are there other reasonings that prove this more "visually"?

Comment: It is 100% correct.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Do I delete this question then or leave it for others?

Comment: You can, but you still have a secondary question, which is whether there's an intuitively appealing explanation that is less "symbolic."